Is there a faster way of expanding multiple polynomials with power?
This question is regarding Limits towards infinity where we have a very large numerator and denominator with polynomials in it.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{9x^{10}+3x-1}{(x^2+3x-5)^3(2x+5)^4}}$$
I know that the trick is to use leading terms to simplify and evaluate this but how do we expand the denominator efficiently given that such question may appear in exams where time is tight. I have learnt of binomial theorem recently but I am unsure of how to apply it in this case.

What's large about it? The denominator is simply $(x^2)^3\cdot(2x)^4$. You've heard about the leading terms, right?

You have answered yourself: use the leading terms and evaluate. The denominator is simply $\left(x^{2}\right)^{3}\left(2x\right)^{4}$

my course requires me to fully expand and get all the coefficients to earn method marks so I wanted to know if there was a faster way of doing so

The trick is to avoid expanding. You are on the right track with leading term. To write it out in an exam,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{9x^{10}+3x-1}{(x^2+3x-5)^3(2x+5)^4}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{9x^{10}(1+1/3x^{-9}-1/9x^{-10})}{x^6(1+3/x-5/x^2)^3(2x)^4(1+5/(2x))^4}}\\=\frac34\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{(1+1/3x^{-9}-1/9x^{-10})}{(1+3/x-5/x^2)^3(1+5/(2x))^4}}$$
Each of the parenthesis evaluates to $1$ in the limit $x\to\infty$

$(x^2+3x-5)^3\sim (x^2)^3=x^6$ and $(2x+5)^4\sim(2x)^4=16 x^4$, hence the limit is $3/4$.
